# C++ NetBEAN F9 Directory Error

Tags: c++, netbeans, compilation

Gives the directory of my project and says "error while loading shared libraries. Cannot open shared objects file: No such file or directory.

> /cygdrive/c/Users/USERNAME/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/cppapplication_2.exe:
>   error while loading shared libraries:
>   ?: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory Press Enter to
>   close the terminal...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could be more clear about what you're doing to cause this error. Not many people are going to know that F9 is a clean and build. I assume you checked that directory to see if it does exist? Did you look at the list of libraries in the project properties?